# How to recreate this reg expression to fit more conditions?

Tags: regex, conditional-statements

Regular expression:

`/(\b|[x])\d{7}\b/`

Essentially what I'm trying to do is only highlight the digits and not the letter "x". I also would like to highlight the 7 digits even if it has multiple spacse between the main number and the 7 digits. I seem to be only be able to highlight expressions when its followed by exactly 1 space.

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not rely on external sites for critical information in your question. Include details in the question if you'd like people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to highlight exactly 7 digits that are followed by space or `x`?

Use this pattern.

```
(?<=[x ])\d{7}(?!\d)
```

`(?<=[x ])` is lookbehind. means only match 7 digits when the preceding character is `x` or whitespace.

`(?!\d)`. is negated lookahead. should be exact 7 digits. so the next character after 7 digits should not be digit.

Comment: Thanks so much! I only learned of regex today so I'm very new to the whole way regex works. It works great! The only thing is, I want to highlight exactly 7 digits after "x" AND after either 1 space or multiple spaces but if and only if its 7 digits.

Comment: I figured it out. I added |[a-z]|[A-Z] which excludes all a-z characters which is what this specific case would be. Thanks for all the help again mate!

Comment: @JimmyQiu you may also do this `(?<=x *)\d{7}(?!\d` but not all regex engines works with lookbehind containing qualifiers. the `x *` means exactly after character `x` with `0` or multiple spaces. the exact 7 digits is specified by `(?!\d)`